# Not receiving Push notification when I forcequit the app

Tags: android, push-notification

I am receiving push notification in my app when someone messages to me from other device when app is in foreground. where as if i forcequit my app using home button, i am not receiving any push notification when user sends me a message. Do I need to pass extra flag in BroadcastReceiver Intent. My app is one to one message receiving app.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your Broadcast receiver in the Manifest to listen in the Baground as well. Baground meaning even after your app is force quitted.

Comment: Yes I have registered my receiver in manifest and not unregistering it when i quit my app.